# Simple include file to node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm new to NodeJS, sorry for a simple question. I have a not-so big program, but want to make my main `web.js` file a bit more clear and create a few separate files (e.g. `user_login.js`, `admin.js`, etc) and **simply paste** these files' contents into `web.js`.

On the Internets everyone is advising to use `require()`, but that means writing a module - a self-consistent piece of code. But I need to simply include text of one file into another. Say, I would have

**admin.js:**

```
app.get('/admin', function (request, response)
{
    response.send("hey, you are an admin!");
});
```

**user.js:**

```
app.get('/', function (request, response)
{
    response.send("hi, how are you?");
}
```

**web.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

include('admin.js');
include('user.js');
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

**admin.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/admin', function(request, response) {
        response.send("hey, you are an admin!");
    });
}
```

**web.js**

```
var app = express();
require('./admin.js')(app);
```

I did not test it, so I might be wrong.

Comment: OK, but what if I have more than one "global" objects (except for `app`). I would have to rewrite each module every time to add these objects to `module.exports=function(app, ...)`?

Comment: I still don't understand the "feature" here. Though I do appreciate "moduleness" and all the stuff, it does not seem to be justified in such simple cases. In my first app I'm already using three modules. So I would have `module.exports = function(app, swig, mongodb) {...}`. But what if next time I want to use MySQL instead of MongoDB, or Jade instead of Swig? or add five more modules? I would have to rewrite everything OR use high-level abstractions (ORM?), additional parameters, etc from the very beginning. This would take a week to learn and write, and still won't be an "overall solution".

Comment: @xaxa: I think, I know what you mean. But when you decide to change the content for your `admin` route for instance, you have to change the function anyway. Only this time you add the arguments to your function´s signature. There is another thing you can consider: How about creating a super object like `awesome`. Store your app in `awesome.app`, your mongo in `awesome.mongo` etc. and pass only the `awesome` object to your route functions. You will not need to change your signatures or function calls anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no reason why you would need something like this.

Node has the built-in module [vm](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html), which can help you in your problem, but there will be a lot of more problems envolving using it.
For example: you'll need to pass a common context to your file, so it'll be able to `require` things at their own. This is very problematic, just write something that uses the standard `module.exports` from Node and forget this PHP thoughts :)

Comment: I'm not actually coming from PHP :) Though `vm` can help, I believe I can with the same luck use `eval(fs.readFile(...))`, but this seems like an overkill for such a simple task.

Answer (score -1):

first:

```
// admin.js
var express=require('express')
var app=express();
app.get('/', function (request, response)
{
    response.send("hey, you are an admin!");
});

module.exports = app;
```

then:

```
// main.js
var express=require("express");
var app = express();
var admin=require("./admin");
app.use("/admin",admin.routes);
```

that's how node and express works. `include` "à la" PHP is an antipattern , and you should not even think about using that.

Comment: So I initialize a (new?) object each time a new file is included? If I want to have 10 files, it means 10 initializations? Such a pattern doesn't look cool)

Comment: doesnt matter , the objects are only initialized once , when you start the server. they are not created on each request. So there is next to no cost. What i'm showing you is a way to make your app modular. that way you can you the same admin app on several projects , for instance.